# Quantum instrument vs POVM

Tags: measurement

In the Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurement_in_quantum_mechanics#Generalized_measurement_(POVM)

They say that the Kraus decomposition of the POVM operators is needed to express the post measurement state

However in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_instrument
The decomposition is not needed and we can express the post measurement state without knowing it.

How to reconciliate these ?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't such a thing as a "Kraus decomposition" of the POVM operators. A POVM $\{E_i\}$ only determines the probabilities of the measurement outcomes, it does *not* determine the post-measurement states. It is very useful when we are only interested in knowing the probabilities, but it is simply not a complete description of the measurement. Perhaps this Wikipedia article will be more clear: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POVM#Post-measurement_state

A quantum instrument, on the other hand, is a complete description, and determines both the probabilities and the post-measurement states. Incidentally, it is easy to compute the Kraus decomposition of a given instrument.

Comment: Is it the complete positivity of each quantum instrument element, as opposed to POVM elements which are only PSD, that makes the Kraus decomposition unique ?

Comment: Again, there is no Kraus decomposition for POVMs. The concept doesn't apply. The Kraus decomposition is in any case never unique.